# Copying a range of cells and paste only values in the same range in another sheet

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

i have this loop, looping through a sheet rows and i need to paste the same range of cells in another sheet with the same structure.

```
 For i = 1 To NumRows 
            
                
                Set rng = sheet.Range("D" & i)
                rng.EntireRow.Copy otherSheet.Cells(i + LastRow, 1)
                
                
                
 Next i
```

Now if i have to paste only values from the Entirerow to the 'otherSheet', how can i achieve this?

Comment: But don't you need to copy all the range from the first row up to the `NumRows`? If yes, it can be copied at once and very fast, using an array... Then, why copying the entire row and not only the used range? Where do you want pasting? In cell "A1", or in the first empty cell of A:A column?

Comment: Why not try the macro recorder or google, this is a common ask?

Comment: Actually i have many sheets that i need to consolidate in a big one  (named  'otherSheet' here).  So i need to remember the last empty row in the big sheet to know where to begin pasting the rows when i pass to the next sheet (i'm looping through the sheets) in the var called Lastrow. what do you mean with "using an array?" could you be more specific? thanks

Comment: I will prepare an answer. I will try commenting it and you will see how such an array can be used. Working only in memory will make the code very fast.

Comment: @FaneDuru thx so much

Comment: Did you test my answer code?

Comment: I'm testing it right now, i will let you know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, test the next code. It assumes that your first row in each sheet can be used like reference to calculate the number of columns to be calculated. If not the case, plese specify which row to be used:

```
Sub testCopyRangeFromAllSheetsToMaster()
 Dim sh As Worksheet, shCons As Worksheet, lastR As Long, lastC As Long
 Dim lastRCons As Long, arr

 Set shCons = Worksheets("otherSheet")    'use here your consolidation sheet to copy the range
 For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    If sh.Name <> shCons.Name Then
        lastR = sh.Range("A" & rows.count).End(xlUp).row  'last row in the sheet to copy from
        lastC = sh.cells(1, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column 'last column
        arr = sh.Range("A1", sh.cells(lastR, lastC)).Value 'Put the range in an array
        lastRCons = shCons.Range("A" & rows.count).End(xlUp).row + 1 'last empty row in the consolidation sheet
        'drop the array content at once:
        shCons.Range("A" & lastRCons).Resize(UBound(arr), UBound(arr, 2)).Value = arr
    End If
 Next sh
 MsgBox "Ready..."
End Sub
```

If you want avoiding copying the headers, you should replace `sh.Range("A1"...` with `sh.Range("A2"...`. This means that the array is built starting with the second row.

Comment: @Syertim: Glad I could help!